# Rails get app url during initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails app and I need to get the URL on which the app is running during the time when the app is initializing (therefore, I can't use any controller `request` variable to ascertain the URL). I'm running on the Puma web server, and on Heroku.

Comment: To do that you need to save app url somewhere in configuration, for example as default mailer host (you have to set it anyway)

Comment: That's precisely what I want the URL for. [Statusify](https://github.com/ur0/statusify), (the app which I'm working on), is meant to be deployed by about anyone, and asking them to set the URL as a config var is something I'd like to avoid. I was looking for a way by which the app would detect the URL without human intervention.

Comment: There is no way to do that unless upon deployment you would have an installer (like wordpress) which would take those values from installer request.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's what I'll be doing.